# How to read a specific folder using MethodChannel in flutter?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I am trying to make an audioplayer which will parse mp3s from a given folder which is preferably outside the app directory like "/storage/emulated/0/musicFiles" or "/sdcard/musicFiles".

Since I am not getting the whole functionality from Flutter I am making use of MethodChannel to call a method which will read the given pre-specified folder and return a List of the files which can be used by the Flutter ListView.builder to display a list.

My current source codes are as:

**main.dart**

```
 class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static const platform = const MethodChannel('player.fileHandler/getFileList');
  List _responseFromNativeCode = [];
  Future<void> responseFromNativeCode() async {
    List response = [];
    try {
      final List result = await platform.invokeMethod('getFileList');
      response = result;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("${e.message}");
    }
    setState(() {
      _responseFromNativeCode = response;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Text("${_responseFromNativeCode.length}"),
            /*RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Call Native Method'),
              onPressed: responseFromNativeCode,
            ),
            //Text(_responseFromNativeCode[0]),
            ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _responseFromNativeCode.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return new Text(_responseFromNativeCode[index]);
              },
            ),*/
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
                .setMethodCallHandler(
                        (call, result) -> {
                            getFileList();
                        }
                );
    }

    private List<String> getFileList(){
        File [] listOfFiles = new File("/sdcard/musicPlayer").listFiles();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
             list.add(listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

The code is supposed to return the paths as a list but the value shown using 
 
`Text("${_responseFromNativeCode.length}")`
 is 0 which means for some reason either the value is not getting sent of I am having a problem in data types.
 Any help would be very nice.

 **Edit**:
I think the MainActivity isn't being called. I put up several Log.d() to check the flow of the control and the content of the list but none of the logs were executed.[image: Shows the logcat and the logs I wrote]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `getFileList` method works as intended, then what you have to do is call `result.success(getFileList())` inside your MethodCallHandler to receive the result in your dart code.

Read more about this here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-java-tab#example